# how to instantiate template of template

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

I have template that looks like this:

```
100 template<size_t A0, size_t A1, size_t A2, size_t A3>
101 struct mask {
103     template<size_t B0, size_t B1, size_t B2, size_t B3>
104     struct compare {
105         static const bool value = (A0 == B0 && A1 == B1 && A2 == B2 && A3 == B3);
106     };
107 };
...
120 const typename boost::enable_if_c<
121 mask<a,b,c,d>::compare<2,3,0,1>::value || ...>::type
```

I am trying to instantiate compare structure. How do I do get value in line 121?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: the parser chokes.  My guess `compare<2`, 121, is interpreted as comparison rather than template

Comment: you could try typedefing mask<a,b,c,d>::compare<2,3,0,1> to a single name to see it it helps, also check you don't have any double close-angle brackets >> which will confuse the parser.

Comment: let's get the terminology right: this isn't a template of a template. a template of a template is a template that takes as its parameter another template, rather than a class: `template<template<class> class T> C { }; C<std::vector> obj;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need template before compare:

```
120 const typename boost::enable_if_c<
121 mask<a,b,c,d>::template compare<2,3,0,1>::value || ...>::type
```

Comment: actually tried it before, however overlooked stray (. 
But now it compiles, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I think you need:

```
const typename boost::enable_if_c< __typename__ mask<a,b,c,d>::compare<2,3,0,1>::value || ...>::type
```